# select and update in single procedure

Tags: mysql, events, triggers, procedure

I have a table which is **tbl_custinfo** (fld_flag,fld_status), in this table the default value for the column **fld_flag** is 0, If I select one row in this table, the column  **fld_status** should be update to 1. Is it possible to create a trigger or procedure or event to this ?

Comment: so you want a ON SELECT trigger?

Comment: @skv yes, But select trigger is not available in mysql, Mostly I worked with oracle.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing called on select trigger.

But you wanted one, the issue is there are innumerable ways of selecting data, and so select is not an action you can base your triggers on.

The closest you can get is actually to make a stored procedure to select data from this table and allow access to this table only to that stored procedure and for none of the users, then in that stored procedure you can update this field value as well.

Hope this helps